# untitled2main.cpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I have install `QT5.0.1 with mingw32` on windows.when i created a project and run it and every thing was perfect. next time when i was opened `QT Qreator` and want to run my program it has following error:

```
:-1: error: error: ..untitled2main.cpp: No such file or directory
```

from build menu i clicked on `qmake`  and it has no error.
this is .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    contentcontrol.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    contentcontrol.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    contentcontrol.ui
```

this is compile output:

```
22:17:17: Running steps for project untitled1...
22:17:17: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:17:17: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/(Mahdi)/Documents/QT/untitled1-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\untitled1 -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\untitled1\main.cpp
g++.exe: error: ..untitled1main.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile.Debug:477: recipe for target 'debug/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/(Mahdi)/Documents/QT/untitled1-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
22:17:18: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

what is problem?

Comment: Did you rename a file?

Comment: No i didn't that.when i create a new project this error exist again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future views:
i solved that with adding values to environment variables

```
path:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin
QTDIR:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Fixed it with setting to true checkbox in **Projects / Buils Environment / Clear system environment**. May be useful for future views.